# R: Error when combining "nearest neighborhood" and "exact" matching from MatchIt Package

Tags: r, matching, exact-match

I'm trying to run a propensity score matching with the nearest neighbor method while I need a exact match on one variable, called "type". My data looks like this:

```
> df
# A tibble: 20 × 6
     symbol treat  type  market.cap market.to.book  leverage
     <fctr> <lgl> <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>     <dbl>
1   AT_ABCB  TRUE     1   228152.66      1.1929613  9.394726
2   AT_ACFC  TRUE     1   162562.19      1.8101484  6.174758
3   AT_ACGL  TRUE     4  4735844.75      1.1734933  3.434948
4   AT_ACNB FALSE     1    91063.20      1.0696958 10.241219
5   AT_AFSI FALSE     4   825553.85      1.9527673  3.257310
6   AT_AGII  TRUE     4  1291845.73      0.9330774  3.870854
7   AT_AINV  TRUE     2  1764811.40      0.9540821  1.948243
8   AT_AMNB  TRUE     1   122196.43      1.2037753  6.489334
9  AT_AMPLQ FALSE     2   426403.00      1.8064556  2.081252
10  AT_AMRB  TRUE     1    95820.71      1.5977307  6.329130
11  AT_AMSF  TRUE     3   291789.63      1.4095641  3.839128
12  AT_AMTD  TRUE     2 11929441.28      5.5359066  2.335973
13  AT_ANAT  TRUE     4  3210435.20      0.8591439  5.587567
14  AT_ANCX FALSE     1    65479.64      1.1297189  9.575704
15 AT_AOREF FALSE     4   133379.89      0.5524693  5.639680
16  AT_ARCC FALSE     2  1063369.56      0.9455956  1.662850
17  AT_AROW  TRUE     1   230742.30      1.8873699  7.329797
18  AT_ASFI  TRUE     2   367991.92      1.5492114  1.897770
19  AT_ASRV  TRUE     1    61463.53      0.6807045 14.029418
20  AT_ATAX FALSE     2    87023.72      1.3613197  2.160063
```

Executing this code:

```
library(MatchIt)
match1 <- matchit(treat ~ market.cap + market.to.book + leverage + type,
                  method = "nearest", replace = TRUE, exact ="type",
                  data = df)
```

leads to the following error:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(exact[itert, k], exact[clabels, k]) : 
  ‘!=’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

The code works fine when I drop the `exact` argument. A similiar code also works with the sample data from `lalonde` provided by the `MatchIt` package:

```
library(MatchIt)
match1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + married, method = "nearest", 
               exact  = "married", replace = TRUE, data = lalonde)
```

So I guess that the data itself causes the problem. Here is the code that reproduces the first 20 rows of my original data. Running the above matching code with this sample data causes the same error as the original data.

```
symbol <- c("AT_ABCB", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACNB", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AGII",
            "AT_AINV", "AT_AMNB", "AT_AMPLQ", "AT_AMRB", "AT_AMSF", "AT_AMTD",
            "AT_ANAT", "AT_ANCX", "AT_AOREF", "AT_ARCC", "AT_AROW", "AT_ASFI",
            "AT_ASRV", "AT_ATAX")

type <- c(1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)

treat <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
           TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)

market.cap <- c(228152.66, 162562.19, 4735844.75, 91063.20, 825553.85, 1291845.73, 
                1764811.40, 122196.43, 426403.00, 95820.71, 291789.63, 11929441.28,
                3210435.20, 65479.64, 133379.89, 1063369.56, 230742.30, 367991.92,
                61463.53, 87023.72)

market.to.book <- c(1.1929613, 1.8101484, 1.1734933, 1.0696958, 1.9527673, 
                    0.9330774, 0.9540821, 1.2037753, 1.8064556, 1.5977307, 
                    1.4095641, 5.5359066, 0.8591439, 1.1297189, 0.5524693,
                    0.9455956, 1.8873699, 1.5492114, 0.6807045, 1.3613197)

leverage <- c(9.394726, 6.174758, 3.434948, 10.241219, 3.257310, 3.870854,
              1.948243, 6.489334, 2.081252, 6.329130, 3.839128, 2.335973,
              5.587567, 9.575704, 5.639680, 1.662850, 7.329797, 1.897770, 
              14.029418, 2.160063)

library(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(data.frame(symbol, treat, type, market.cap, 
                        market.to.book, leverage))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
df <- data.frame(symbol, treat, type, market.cap, market.to.book, leverage)
```

Comment: Thanks -- just an extension note here that this is another case where tibbles won't play nicely with other functions, so ensuring the data being passed to `matchit` is a regular data frame solves the issue.